# Why is android converting my base class to it's parent class when i put it as an extra?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have a class which just helps me to save time so i don't always have to write the long class name:

```
public class ImageBucket extends ArrayList<LoadableGeoLocationImage> implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4275196266297013629L;

    public ImageBucket() {}

    public ImageBucket(Collection<? extends LoadableGeoLocationImage> collection) {
        super(collection);
    }

    public ImageBucket(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

    public ImageBucket(ImageBucket ... buckets){
        super();

        for(ImageBucket bucket: buckets){
            this.addAll(bucket);
        }
    }
}
```

I use this class to pass data from Activity A to Activity B:

```
    ImageBucket images = this.getImages();

    System.err.println(images.getClass().getName()); // Prints: .....ImageBucket

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.INTENT_ARG_IMAGES, images);
```

But when i try to get my data i get a ClassCastException:

```
    Serializable seriImgBucket = this.getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(INTENT_ARG_IMAGES);
    System.err.println(seriImgBucket.getClass().getName()); //Prints: ....ArrayList

    this.images = (ImageBucket) seriImgBucket;
```

Why does android return me the base class and not the one i added to the extras and how can i fix that?

Comment: @Squonk. A pointless suggestion. What will happen will be a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, through this code

```
Serializable seriImgBucket = this.getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(INTENT_ARG_IMAGES);
```

the ImageBucket class had been cast to its superclass, and this process can't be reversible.
So, I advice you to modify it like this

```
ImageBucket seriImgBucket = this.getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(INTENT_ARG_IMAGES);
```

Also, it may help you to save some code! Good luck!

Comment: I had it like this, after i got the ClassCastExceptions i changed my code like it is now in the answer to print the actual class names.